# Add WhatsApp contacts in bulk

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I want to save 1000's WhatsApp contacts that were not added to the contact list in bulk.

[image]

Which is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Store all the numbers in csv file and than

On your computer, go to Google Contacts.
On the left, click More and then Import.
In the window that appears, choose how you'd like to import your contacts
Check that you saved your contacts as a .csv or .vcf file. Then click CSV or vCard file  and then Select file.
Click Import.
Than let the contact sync with your mobile